# Memory efficient load of multiple CSVs into a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue where I need to load multiple CSV files into a single pandas dataframe. I cannot use `pd.concat` because it requires the dataframes to be preloaded and this causes a duplication in RAM usage - but the files are large and fit in memory only once..

Is there an alternative method to iteratively construct the dataframe?

Comment: if files have the same columns in the same order then you could append one file to another using only `open()`, `read()`, `write()` (and it would need to skip first row with headers) - and later you could load all as one file. But if problem is small RAM then maybe load files paritally and make calculations only on some part of data and append results to some file partially. OR you will have to buy better computer (or use some servers on internet)

Comment: @furas I'm aware. My question is whether there's a way to do in pandas.

Comment: [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) has option `chunksize` to read file partially but still it will need memory to keep all result. As for me answer is: don't use pandas.

Comment: you may write paritally - with `append mode` - so you don't have to create all data in memory but read one file by file and write to the same output file (using `append mode`). And later read all data from one file.